# Inflate view from Resource layout after on click event

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, layout-inflater

I am relatively new to android development and there are a few ideas I am having trouble getting my head around.

What I am trying to achieve is when a button is clicked, a view is inflated to a `LinearLayout` of `R.id.resultsBox`. My idea behind what I think I have to do is this:

```
public class FindClassFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button search_button;
    private EditText course_abbrev_field;
    private EditText course_num_field;
    private Spinner semester_spinner;
    private String course_abbrev;
    private String course_num;
    private String semester;
    private ArrayList<String[]> sectionsList;

    private LinearLayout resultsBox;

    private WebScraper scraper;

    public FindClassFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_findclass, container, false);
        resultsBox = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultsView);
        RelativeLayout f = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section, null);

        search_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        course_abbrev_field = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.course_abbrev);
        course_num_field = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.course_num);

        assert search_button != null;
        search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                System.out.println("CLICK");

                if(true) {
                    resultsBox.removeAllViews();
                    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) view.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.error, (ViewGroup) view);
                    resultsBox.addView(l);
                } else {
                    resultsBox.removeAllViews();
                }

            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I figured out how to get the click event working. `"CLICK"` is printed to the log when I click it. I thought I inflated the view correctly but obviously not because the application crashed.

I'm assuming my error has something to do with inheritance from the `FindClassFragment` class to the `new View.OnClickListener()` sub class but I'm just not sure *what* exactly.

I tried defining everything in the scope of the class but that didn't work... I'm lost.

A helpful hint in the right direction is more than appreciated!

**EDIT: Not worried about variable null pointer exceptions, I'm worried about getting the view to inflate correctly.**

The error log I am getting is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
        at github.m_porter.fragments.FindClassFragment$1.onClick(FindClassFragment.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17967)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5329)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For those who don't like to count, line 67 is `LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) view.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.error, (ViewGroup) view);`

Comment: Can you share the log of the error you're getting?

Comment: I'd love too but it seems like the log is streaming at a billion lines per second but if you know what to filter out then that would be great.

Comment: you should be able to filter the error message easily using your IDE's built in functionalities.

Comment: Updated with error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line# 67 in onClick() of FindClassFragment class is giving NullPointer exception.

Put break point and check which object/variable is null fix that first and give a try.

Edited:
Couldn't find semester_spinner initialized in the code. Initialize it before using it.

Edited:

Use like this:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.error,null);
resultsBox.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Check my update. I removed all the variable null pointer exceptions because that's not what my question is originally about. The error is now occurring with `LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) view.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.error, (ViewGroup) view);`

Comment: Instead of getApplicationContext() use context. Pass the context from Activity to this fragment (in constructor) and than use it.

Comment: I figured out what to do. I changed `getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity()` and it worked perfectly. Change it in your answer and you'll get he check for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

At line 67, the view that you are referring to is the search_button. The view that is being clicked.

Obviously it cannot be cast to ViewGroup...